# sorting based on a field that was not modified - will it use the index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

This is a query of my APP that returns a list of users. After the `$match` stage, some fields will be modified and a `$lookup` stage is involved to find and remove blocked users.

However, the `distance` field is not modified. Will MongoDB be smart enough to recognize that it can sort this query using the index on `distance`?

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {},
  },
  {
    $set: {
      name: "$last_name",
    },
  },
  ...function_to_lookup_and_remove_blocked_users(),
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      distance: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      distance: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: 50,
  },
]);
```

Comment: Move the $sort up into the second position in the pipeline.  Also, what is the filter in the $match and what is the index that you want the query to use?

Comment: I think you helped me alot. I always thought that you have to keep the $sort and $limit together.

Comment: Also, what if I have a $skip stage. where do I put that?

Comment: You can use $skip stage always before $limit stage